# Error al mandar llamar mi frame principal desde un frame de Login

Tags: java

El problema es que al ejecutar mi proyecto dentro de Netbeans si funciona, pero cuando le pongo clean and build para crear el .jar, ejecuto el proyecto en jar, ingreso los datos del usuario me sale el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fragmento de codigo donde creo esta el error es este:

```
public void ComprobarBD() {
    try {
        PS = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
        RS = PS.executeQuery();
        if (RS.next()) {
            BaseUser = RS.getString(1);
            BasePass = RS.getString(2);
            if (TFUsuario.getText().equals(BaseUser) && PFContraseña.getText().equals(BasePass)) {
                Inicio ini = new Inicio();
                ini.setVisible(true);

                Inicio.LabelNombreUsuario.setText(BaseUser);
                Inicio.LabelCorreo.setText("Biblioteca ENESMAPO plantel 4");
                //Inicio.LabelImg.setText(String.valueOf(BaseUser.charAt(0)).toUpperCase());
                Inicio.LabelRoll.setText(RS.getString(3));
                this.dispose();
                new JToast().makeToast(this, "Accediste correctamente.", 2);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has iniciado correctamente");
            } else {
                ErrorPass.setText("Datos no validos");
                ContrasenaOlvidada.setText("¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?");
                jPanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
                jPanel3.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + e, "Error al iniciar la base de datos", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    ErrorPass.setText("Datos no validos");
    ContrasenaOlvidada.setText("¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?");
    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.red);
    jPanel3.setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

La conexión con la base de datos esta funcionando.

Podrían decirme que estoy haciendo mal? :/

El error que obtengo con el metodo printStackTrace
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer el problema esta en el frame Inicio en el metodo IconoInicio(), como lo comentó Alvaro, creo que puede ser por la ruta de las imagenes, algun consejo de como asignarlas? 
Aqui el codigo de alguna de ellas...

```
imgIconH = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/Pixel.jpg"));
        imgEscaladaH = imgIconH.getImage().getScaledInstance(650, 500, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        iconoEscaladoH = new ImageIcon(imgEscaladaH);
        LabelHead.setIcon(iconoEscaladoH);
```

Images es un paquete que contiene todas las imagenes utilizadas, cabe mencionar que al comentar el metodo IconoInicio() el programa funciona correctamente.

Comment: Necesitas ver la causa de la excepción. El mensaje puede estar bien para el usuario, pero tú necesitas ver donde ocurrió el error, o sea con un excepcion.printStackTrace a un archivo o en un componente swing.

Comment: Hola. Edita por favor tu pregunta agregando la traza del error como comenta AlbertoLopez. Por favor también indícanos a que tipo de base de datos de estas conectando. Debo comentarte también que no estas siguiendo los estándares de nombres de Java. Por otro lado este tipo de error suele presentarse cuando se esta haciendo referencia a un recurso (un archivo, una imagen, un audio, una BD embebida ) con una ruta que tiene sentido cuando se ejecuta desde el IDE y que no lo tiene cuando se ejecuta desde el jar.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: ¿Has incluido la imagen en el classpath del jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero comprueba que la imagen está en jar. Esto puedes hacerlo con el siguiente comando (Sé que en Unix es este, en windows no estoy seguro):

```
jar -tf C:\rutaDelJar\nombre.jar
```

Si tu imagen no está incluida deberás incluirla en el classpath del jar.

Para hacer esto tienes dos opciones:

**1) Incluir la imagen en el source package.**

De esta forma la imagen se incluirá en el classpath del jar.

**2) 
   Agregar el directorio de imágenes como raíz de origen para tu proyecto**

En netbeans tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

Haz clic derecho en el proyecto y selecciona "Propiedades": 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparecerá un diálogo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Selecciona "Sources" en la lista que se encuentra en el lado
  izquierdo del diálogo.
- Presiona el botón 'Add folder' que aparece junto a la tabla "Source
  package folder". Aparecerá un FileChooser.
- Usa este selector para seleccionar la carpeta de imágenes y presione
  el botón OK. Se agregará una entrada para la carpeta de imágenes.
- Pulsa el botón "aceptar" en el cuadro de diálogo Propiedades del
  proyecto para aceptar los cambios y cerrar el cuadro de diálogo.

Por ultimo pulsa clean and rebuild, esto te generará un nuevo archivo .jar del tu proyecto.

**¿Qué es lo que has hecho aquí?**

Lo que hace java al crear un archivo jar, es incluir todos los archivos .class, .java... que tengas en el source package en el jar. Si tienes un paquete fuera del source, no se incluirá y por eso te saldrá una excepción de tipo NPE. Lo que haces en **(2)** es decirle a java: ¡Eh, incluyeme este paquete también en el jar! Así de esta forma tendrás todos los archivos del paquete dentro del jar. ¡Espero que te ayude!

Comment: Ya resolví el problema, era un error en la ruta de una imagen, pero tu respuesta también me ayudó a incluir la ruta de todas esas imágenes. Gracias.